# Unable to generate clientAccessUri for WebPubSubClient in typescript with @azure/web-pubsub and @azure/web-pubsub-client

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuejs2, azure-web-pubsub, azure-pubsub

I'm trying to use the Azure Web Pun Sub Service in my vuejs application which does the publish & subscribe both to a specific group (which is supposed to create dynamically and add users to this).
Looking into the examples provide for @azure/web-pubsub and @azure/web-pubsub-client npm package it seems to be very easy but the moment I start with the code, I got first struggled with building the project because **uncaught exceptions for 'crypto', 'stream', 'Buffer', and 'chile_process' is not defined** but I was able to fix this by installing npm packages crypto-browserify, stream-browserify and buffer and also added fallback settings in my webpack.config.js.

```
fallback: { // not present by default
                "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
                "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
                "buffer": require.resolve("buffer"),
                //"util": false,
                "child_process": false,
            }
```

The above fixes, help me to build the project successfully but I was unable to get the Azure pub-sub service client access URL to create the instance of WebPubSubClient. here is my code:

```
const key = new AzureKeyCredential(WPS_APIKEY);
                const serviceClient = new WebPubSubServiceClient(WPS_ENDPOINT, key, hubName);
                const fetchClientAccessUrl = async (_: GetClientAccessUrlOptions) => {
                    return (
                        await serviceClient.getClientAccessToken({
                            roles: [`webpubsub.joinLeaveGroup.${groupName}`, `webpubsub.sendToGroup.${groupName}`],
                        })
                    ).url;
                };
                let client = new WebPubSubClient({
                    getClientAccessUrl: fetchClientAccessUrl,
                } as WebPubSubClientCredential);
client.on("connected", (e) => {
                    console.log(`Connection ${e.connectionId} is connected.`);
                });

                client.on("disconnected", (e) => {
                    console.log(`Connection disconnected: ${e.message}`);
                });
                await client.start();
                await client.joinGroup(groupName);
                await client.sendToGroup(groupName, {
                    conversationId: this.$data.conversation.conversationId,
                    conversationContext: this.$data.conversation.conversationContext,
                    message: {
                        messageId: 100,
                        message: `Hello, You are welcome to the group: ${groupName}`,
                        timestamp: "08-06 06:20 PM",
                        sender: this.user.userName
                    }
                }, "json");
```

The above code fails when the client.start() executes and it tries to fetchClientAccessUrl with the above code func, with an error: "**Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object**" inside jsonwebtoken/sign.js file at line no. 108 where the code is:

```
 if (secretOrPrivateKey != null && !(secretOrPrivateKey instanceof KeyObject)) {
    try {
      secretOrPrivateKey = createPrivateKey(secretOrPrivateKey)
    } catch (_) {
      try {
        secretOrPrivateKey = createSecretKey(typeof secretOrPrivateKey === 'string' ? Buffer.from(secretOrPrivateKey) : secretOrPrivateKey)
      } catch (_) {
        return failure(new Error('secretOrPrivateKey is not valid key material'));
      }
    }
  }
```

Note: I have not installed the NPM package 'jsonwebtoekn' instead it came from '@azure/identity'.

Also, I get the same error while I'm trying to create a group and add users with the below code:

```
const key = new AzureKeyCredential(WPS_APIKEY);
const chatHub = new WebPubSubServiceClient(WPS_ENDPOINT, key, hubName);
let groupExists = await checkGroupExists(groupName);
        if (!groupExists) {
            let group = await chatHub.group(groupName);
            users.forEach(async usr => {
                await group.addUser(usr);
            });
        }
```

I tried a lot but had no luck. Can anyone please help me to understand if I'm doing something wrong here?

Here is the list of npm dependencies that my project has along with node (v20.2.0) and npm (v9.6.3).

```
"dependencies": {
        "@azure/identity": "^3.2.2",
        "@azure/web-pubsub": "^1.1.1",
        "@azure/web-pubsub-client": "^1.0.0-beta.3",
        "axios": "0.21.4",
        "core-js": "3.25.3",
        "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
        "msal": "^1.4.18",
        "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
        "util": "^0.12.5",
        "uuid": "^9.0.0",
        "vue": "2.6.14",
        "vue-i18n": "8.27.2",
        "vue-router": "3.5.2",
        "vuex": "3.6.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "7.15.5",
        "@babel/eslint-parser": "7.15.7",
        "@babel/preset-env": "7.15.6",
        "@types/jest": "27.4.0",
        "@types/node": "17.0.16",
        "@types/uuid": "^9.0.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.11.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.11.0",
        "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "9.1.0",
        "@vue/test-utils": "1.2.2",
        "@vue/vue2-jest": "27.0.0-alpha.2",
        "babel-loader": "8.2.2",
        "clean-webpack-plugin": "4.0.0",
        "concurrently": "7.4.0",
        "cors": "2.8.5",
        "css-loader": "6.2.0",
        "dotenv-webpack": "7.0.3",
        "eslint": "7.32.0",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "8.0.1",
        "eslint-webpack-plugin": "3.2.0",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "5.3.2",
        "jest": "27.3.1",
        "jest-fetch-mock": "3.0.3",
        "jest-sonar-reporter": "2.0.0",
        "mini-css-extract-plugin": "2.5.3",
        "nodemon": "2.0.20",
        "postcss-loader": "6.1.1",
        "process": "0.11.10",
        "sass": "1.41.1",
        "sass-loader": "12.1.0",
        "serve": "12.0.1",
        "stylelint": "13.13.1",
        "stylelint-config-sass-guidelines": "8.0.0",
        "terser-webpack-plugin": "5.2.4",
        "ts-jest": "27.1.3",
        "ts-loader": "9.2.6",
        "typescript": "5.1.3",
        "vue-loader": "15.9.8",
        "vue-remove-attributes": "1.0.3",
        "vue-template-compiler": "2.6.14",
        "webpack": "5.74.0",
        "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "4.6.1",
        "webpack-cli": "4.10.0",
        "webpack-dev-server": "4.11.1"
    },
```

Comment: It seems @azure/web-pubsub npm package APIs are not expected to run on browser client. Hence I switched to nodejs and later azure function to get the Azure web pubsub access url.

Answer (score 0):

You can use backend i.e. NodeJs, Azure Functions or C# APIs to generate the access url. @Azure/Web-pubsub has a dependency with @Azure/Identity which internally uses jsonwebtoken and this is not working as expected (or not supposed to) in-browser client. Hence You can use any backend server to generate the access url for azure web pubsub service. In my case, I used NodeJs with Azure Function to get the url. Here is example for Azure Function NodeJs code:

```
const { WebPubSubServiceClient, AzureKeyCredential } = require('@azure/web-pubsub');

module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');
    const { groupName, id, hubName } = req.body;
    const key = new AzureKeyCredential("<Azure web PubSub Servic Key>");
    const serviceClient = new WebPubSubServiceClient("https://<Azure web PubSub Service HostName>", key, hubName);
    
    if (!id || !groupName) {
        context.res.status(400).send('missing user id & group name');
    }
    let token = await serviceClient.getClientAccessToken({
        userId: id, expirationTimeInMinutes: 60, roles: [
            `webpubsub.sendToGroup.${groupName}`,
            `webpubsub.joinLeaveGroup.${groupName}`
        ]
    });
    context.res.json({
        url: token.url
    });
}
```